# Is there a cleaner way to use local scope when creating a variable?

Tags: typescript

I'm coming from the ML world where you can create a variable like this:

```
let myVar =
    let result1 = doSomething()
    let result2 = doSomethingElse()
    result1 + result2
```

Note that `result1` and `result2` are only visible in that 3-line scope, nowhere else. This is very nice to avoid naming clashes and pollution.

In TypeScript, looks like you can use anonymous functions for that:

```
const myVar = 
    function() {
        const result1 = doSomething();
        const result2 = doSomethingElse();
        return result1 + result2;        
    }();
```

But this double-indents everything and makes it look like you're declaring a function rather than a value. Is there a cleaner or more explicit way to go about this?

Comment: `const myVar = doSomething() + doSomethingElse();`? Or give a name to this function, and call it by its name?

Comment: Thanks but that misses the point. The question is how to use local scope in a variable declaration; this simply avoids it.

Comment: It only double indents everything because you chose to put the `function() {`on its own indented line. You can just put it at the end of the previous line, and still have one indentation level (as shown in AKX's answer).

Comment: @Asik That's not what was asked.  You asked if there was a cleaner way of doing this.  I suggest editing the question to clarify what you want.

Comment: @Amy the title is "Is there a cleaner way to use local scope when creating a variable?"

Comment: @Asik And the top comment is a cleaner way of doing that, yet you're saying its not what you want.

Comment: It does not use a local scope. The question is about a cleaner way to use local scope, the code posted illustrating an example of using local scope.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a fat-arrow function for an IIFE:

```
const myVar = (() => {
  const result1 = doSomething();
  const result2 = doSomethingElse();
  return result1 + result2;
})();
```

But why not just

```
const myVar = doSomething() + doSomethingElse();
```

?

If the actual expressions for `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()` are large enough that that seems cumbersome, it smells like they should be refactored into real functions anyway.

Comment: In that particular case yes, you could refactor it as a one-liner, but sometimes you cannot. It was meant as a simple example.